# HTTP Connection Parameters

Tags: http, blackberry, java-me, cellular-network

I am using the HTTP Connection in the following way:

```
         HttpConnection _httpConnection = null;

         try {
             _httpConnection = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(_url);
         } catch(Exception e) { }

        byte [] postDataBytes = _postData.getBytes();
        _httpConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
        _httpConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.0");
        _httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
        _httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        _httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
        _httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(_postData.getBytes().length));

        os = _httpConnection.openOutputStream();
        os.write(postDataBytes);
        os.flush();
```

This HTTP Connection requires parameters to successfully open. For example on a WIFI network, it requires the ";deviceside=true;interface=wifi" to be added to the URL.

The problem is for the EDGE connection. Each country requires different parameters to be added. For example in lebanon it requires ";deviceside=false" but in KSA if i add this parameter the connection will not open. In USA it needs different types of parametes. The question is how to establish an HTTP connection for all the countries with the same parameters. So that the application will successfully have an internet connection no matter where it is downloaded.

Comment: Are you confusing the link layer with the transport?  For example, you can get a BES connection (`deviceside=false`) over EDGE or CDMA or even WiFi.  But you can only get a BES connection if the device is associated with a BES environment.  For example, most consumer devices are not associated with BES, but with BIS instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to the confusing world of network transports on BlackBerry!  You will want to start with the article [Connecting your BlackBerry - http and socket connections to the world](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Connecting-your-BlackBerry-http-and-socket-connections-to-the/td-p/206242).

Here is a simple example for "just give me a connection" (note, you will need to add appropriate error handling; also, `myURL` in the code below should have no connection descriptor info appended to it):

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
ConnectionDescriptor descriptor = factory.getConnection(myURL);
if (descriptor != null) {
    _httpConnection = (HttpConnection) descriptor.getConnection();
    ...
}
```

Comment: I spent days reading this post without any general conclusion... Did you found anything that may make this post useful in my case?

Comment: What OS versions are you targeting?  I found the networking API in OS5+ (`ConnectionFactory` et. al.) much easier to use and more flexible.

Comment: I am targeting OS 5.0 and above. I saw the ConnectionFactory API but didn't know how to use it!! I tried different examples but failed to succeed. Could you give me some help?

Comment: This didn't work ... No connection available for the edge connection just it worked for WIFI

Comment: Are you using a real device or a simulator?  If a real device, are you sure the device is properly provisioned and configured and has an appropriate data package?  You could also try setting a preferred connection order with `factory.setPreferredTransporTypes()`.

Comment: If a real device, are you sure the device is properly provisioned and configured and has an appropriate data package? What do you mean by this? Didn't get you properly

Comment: @FaridFarhat Hey Farid did this solved your issue??? i am also facing the same issue can you please explain me how you solved this issue????Its really urgent.

Answer (score 0):

Try using to use the method reffered in this link [melick-rajee.blogspot.com](http://melick-rajee.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-connect-to-internet-using.html) and use it like

```
_url = "http://www.example.com";

_httpConnection = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(_url + getConnectionString());
```

You will have to sign the application to use this else the application will show exception.
To sign your application just go here [Code Signing Keys](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/codekeys.jsp)

Comment: Could not connet via EDGE!! same problem

Answer (score 0):

To use the connectionFactory, seems you need to set [BisBOptions](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/io/transport/options/BisBOptions.html).

Try this:

```
    connFact = new ConnectionFactory();
    connFact.setTransportTypeOptions(TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_BIS_B,
                    new BisBOptions("mds-public"));
```